# Where is a good place to farm experience in Terranigma?

Tags: terranigma

Been playing Terranigma, I'm not very familiar with the different amounts of XP gained from different monsters, though it seems fairly easy to guess on normal guys.

After you can already travel the world (I'm just now getting to the lab part..) what's a good monster/location to hunt for quicker leveling?

Comment: I won't post an answer, since it's been years since I played this so I might be forgetting a detail, but generally, wherever the current dungeon is is the best unless they're particularly hard to kill for some reason.  I would also point out (VERY MINOR SPOILER -----) that you're almost at the end of the game.

Comment: yea i know  i just kinda wanted to max out my character and wondered which monster had the highest xp, thanks though ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're headed for the lab, it has an excellent place to gain XP. It's a short corridor (two screens) with 4 enemies giving 100 XP each. Just run back and forth right there and you'll get to level 35+ pretty fast.

This room is on the second floor, right where you flip the switch to open access to the 3rd floor:

[image: terranigma best place to level up]

Image comes from [this useful walkthrough](http://shrines.rpgclassics.com/snes/terranigma/wberuga.shtml) which also recommends the same room for getting XP.

Comment: Also turned out if you just run in circles between that room and some teleports, you can net some good speed ;p Perfect location

Comment: I prefer killing the two cubes one floor lower. They give 102 experience each and are easy to kill without danger.

Comment: Also in the canals under Neotokio there are these small round robots. 99 XP each and 5 near a door and easy to kill. It is the long horizontal hallway with the water flowing in the middle, where you first see the girl and the lion.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of obscure and I'm not 100% sure, but I believe one of the early bosses (in a cave, possibly a large insect?) has a corner you can sit in and set your controller to turbo on, then just leave for a while and come back. It spits out a bunch of minor enemies that die in one hit (or should, if you grind a bit before) and makes for an endless experience jackpot over time.